# First Mapper produces output from another block (file) and the 1st part files generated holds data from block 2

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

First Mapper produces output from another block (file) and the 1st part files generated holds data from block 2.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class MainMaxTemp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setNumReduceTasks(2);
        job.setJarByClass(MainMaxTemp.class);
        job.setJobName("Max temperature");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setMapperClass(WeatherData.class);
        // job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}


import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class WeatherData extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private static final int MISSING = 9999;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String words[]=line.split(" ");
        String year = words[0];
        int airTemperature;

        airTemperature=Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
        context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemperature));

    }
}
```

Input file 1 
1901 23
1902 67
1902 89
1901 101
1889 -90
1700 189
1901 -9

Input file 2
2901 23
2902 67
2902 89
2901 101
2889 -90
2700 189
2901 -9

part file 1
1700    189
1889    -90
1902    89
1902    67
2901    -9
2901    101
2901    23

part file 2
1901    -9
1901    101
1901    23
2700    189
2889    -90
2902    89
2902    67

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i was unable to understand why out files are mixing, i got an answer probably. Since the count of reducers is set to 2 the output part files are mixing up.